# Iterating through $_FILES array to perform exec()

Tags: php, python, html

So i've got a python script, which is being executed using the exec() command through embedded PHP. Currently, the python script takes just one file (uploaded using a standard HTML form), but I want to pass it multiple files, and have it run through them every time. I've tried the following code based on some examples I saw here on StackOverflow, but can't seem to get it to work. Does anyone know how I can do it? I just need to get the tmp_file name and the name, then pass them to the exec function, I want it to run once for each file (with the respective information for each file).

```
 <?php 
 foreach ($_FILES["inputFile"]{
    $dataIn = $_FILES["inputFile"]["tmp_name"];
    $originalName = $_FILES["inputFile"]["name"];
    exec("python /home/will/public_html/OrderAnalyser.py $dataIn $originalName 2>&1",$output);
    foreach ($output as $out){
        echo $out;
        echo "<br />";
    }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: What are the errors? Your Code is vulnerable to Code Injection!!

Comment: With this code, it's simply skipping over it, it does not seem to execute the script at all. And understood, it shouldn't be an issue as this will be entirely internal, and i'm just creating the base, someone else will be sorting those sort of things before it goes live.

Comment: for sure you should be validating the data you take from these filename strings, compare them with a valid format, I mean. This is an example code for your Files loop: http://www.w3bees.com/2013/02/multiple-file-upload-with-php.html 

... foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
     if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
         continue; // Skip file if any error found
     }

Comment: if your code is skipped, $_FILES is empty. Make sure you set the enctype of the form on the frontend to enctype="multipart/form-data"